# Merge 2 pdf files & download on button click in angular 4+

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular7, pdf.js

I'm using "jspdf": "^1.5.3" package in my  "@angular/cli": "~7.0.7" project,

I have created simple file using pdf library as below, now the requirement is append http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf pdf to my created jsPDF file & download it.

```
//app.component.ts file
   <a (click)="download();">ClickHere</a>

//app.component.ts file
import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf'

download() {
  var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', 'letter');    
  var pageHeight = doc.internal.pageSize.height;
  var y = 800;
  var x = 800;
  doc.text(100, 100, 'com1');

  if (y >= pageHeight) {
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(100, 100, 'com1');
    y = 0;
  }
  if (x >= pageHeight) {
    doc.addPage();
    doc.text(100, 100, 'com1');
    x = 0;
  }

  const merge = require('easy-pdf-merge');
  merge(doc, 'http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf', function (err) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err)
  }
  console.log('Success')
  });
  doc.save('TemporaryIdCard.pdf');
}
```

It shows error Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in /node_modules/easy-pdf-merge/distribution/lib'

Comment: Did you resolve your issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: Haven't tried it, but you might have a look at https://pdf-lib.js.org/